# How to place dynamic barcodes on multipage document using XSLFO

Tags: barcode, xsl-fo

I have a requirement where the pdf is a multiple page document.I want to place barcode on the page and the value of the barcode should set from a data source. How can i identify the page number and accordingly set the barcode value for that page?

Comment: How are you doing your barcodes now? Are you using a barcode font?

Comment: <xsl:template name="get-barcode"> 
    <xsl:param name="page"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($page, '1')">
    <xf:barcode type="3of9" draw-text="false" fo:content-width="1.83in" fo:content-scaling="uniform" fo:color="black">
<xsl:attribute name="value">
<xsl:value-of select="/Data/BC1"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xf:barcode>
</xsl:when><xsl:otherwise><xf:barcode type="3of9" draw-text="false" fo:content-width="1.83in" fo:content-scaling="uniform" fo:color="red"><xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="/Data/BC2"/></xsl:attribute></xf:barcode>

Comment: In the above code it always executes the otherwise logic as it the page number is not available until the rendering is done.

Comment: I've never used `<xf:barcode>` before. I only have experience with RenderX and FOP as FO processors. You should be able to get the page number using `<fo:page-number/>`, but I'm not sure how you'd use it with your processor. What is your processor?

Comment: Also, are you using a "page" param to supply the page number? Are you using normal `<fo:page-sequence>` for your pages?

Comment: i am using -  <xsl:with-param name="page" select="fo:page-number"/>

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the engine. If you are using the Ecrion [XSL-FO Engine](http://www.ecrion.com/Products/XFRenderingServer/Overview.aspx) then you can use the following placeholders:

**Simple barcodes:**

`$pageNumber`
`$pageIdx`

```
<fo:block text-align="center"> 
 <xf:barcode type="3of9"
   include-checksum="false" value="This
   is page $pageNumber" extended="true" fo:font="8.5pt Helvetica" 
   fo:color="navy"/> 
</fo:block>
```

**Javascript barcodes:**

page-sequence properties: `$pageNumber`, `$pageIdx`, `$sheetIdx`

document properties: `$documentPageIdx`, `$documentSheetIdx`, `$documentPageCount`, `$documentIdx`

merge context(DAL) properties: `$mergedPageIdx`, `$mergedSheetIdx`, `$mergedPageCount`

```
<xf:barcode type="3of9" 
 include-checksum="false" 
 value="javascript:function run(){return 'Javascript: Page $pageNumber';}run();" 
 extended="true" fo:font="8.5pt Helvetica" fo:color="navy" 
 fo:content-width="7.051in" fo:scaling="uniform"/>
```